# How to UPDATE column1 based on a string in column2?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I seem to have a small problem with updating a column within my database (postgres). I am trying to update column1, based on the string which is in column2. The logic behind it is; IF string contains "rail", then column 2 = "rail". IF string contains "air", then column 2 = "air".

I am trying to use CASE to make this work, and would eventually like to put this in a trigger.

I have searched through stackoverflow to find the solution, I see many similar problems but none of them worked for me.

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = CASE
                WHEN column2 LIKE '%rail%' THEN 'rail'
                WHEN column2 LIKE '%air%' THEN 'air'
                ELSE 'other'
                END;
```

I expect column 1 to output either rail, air or other. But it is only printing "other".

(UPDATE) - Solved problem, turns out case sensitivity within the '%%' field is important!

Comment: Storing data as a result of another column is a bit risky. A trigger, to ensure data consistency, is a great idea! (Or create a view.)

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=73940b6e033156741c170d8b29cc986b

Comment: Your query is not doing what you describe. You say you want to update column 2 based on column 1, but the query updates column 1 based on column 2. Other than that, the query looks fine, as demonstrated by S-Man.

Comment: Show us an example of column1/column2 data that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Your SQL looks no problem.

Comment: Solved! The problem was with capitalization within "%%". Thank you for your responses confirming the code was actually correct though.